# Configure a new toolbar for CKEDITOR with Rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using the ckeditor gem like this:

```
# GEMFILE
gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.3'
```

And then in my activeadmin form I show it:

```
# admin/starts.rb
f.input :expertpro, as: :ckeditor, label: "Predictor", input_html: {ckeditor: { toolbar: 'basic' }}
```

And I have set the new toolbar in the config.js:

```
#app/javascript/ckeditor/reconfig.js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
  // config.language = 'fr';
  // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

  /* Filebrowser routes */
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures?command=QuickUpload&type=Images";

  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

  config.allowedContent = true;

  // Toolbar groups configuration.
  config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ], items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
    // { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
    // { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
    { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image',  'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote',  '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format',  'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] }
  ];
  config.toolbar_basic = [
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-',  'Blockquote' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [  'Styles' ] }, 
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
  ];
  config.toolbar_mini = [
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list',  'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList',  '-', 'Blockquote' ] },
    { name: 'styles', items: [ Styles ] },
   
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },    
  ];
};
```

However the full toolbar is shown, or if I try to use the mini toolbar instead of basic, the new config is not used - the default mini toolbar with more buttons is shown.

in my active_admin.js file I am including the config.js file:

```
# app/javascript/admin/active_admin.js
//= require active_admin/base
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require ckeditor/reconfig    
//= require active_admin/searchable_select
```

Looking at the resulting assets/admin/active_admin-xxx-js,  the reconfig.js code is being output to that file and included in the page.

However, the gem is also including /app/assets/config.js after the active_admin.js file, which is overriding my config.  My app is Rails 7, I do not have a javascript dir in my assets dir.

How can I override the default config.js file and define my own toolbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, and now i feel silly. I dont think I realised that I can still use the asset pipeline for javascript, if needed.

So i moved my config to `/app/assets/ckeditor/config.js` and now that is used instead of the default.

I didn't have to add an entry into a manifest or anything.  It just worked.

Comment: how did you install the ckeditor in your rails 7?

Comment: i counter this error /configuration.rb:96:in `method_missing': undefined method `assets' for